# How can I force Finder to be opened in a specific size?

Tags: finder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mac OS X Lion Finder Window Size](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25893/mac-os-x-lion-finder-window-size)

Every time I open Finder it open in a small windows I want it open in a bigger window how can I do this?

Comment: @Nathan Greenstein I was just wondering why you marked  my question as a duplicate? if you check the date you will see I asked this question 2 yeas ago since the other one was asked 1 year ago!

Answer (score 4):

The way to set up a "default" Finder window is indeed a bit obscure: first you'll open a new Finder window, and then **without clicking on any file or folder** arrange the window to your needs (resize, position, define view, show/hide sidebar, etc.) and close it again immediately. Every new window should now use this new setup as a default.

Comment: No, in my OS X 10.6.6 didn't work like this :(

Comment: @Am1rr3cA Huh, that´s strange, since this is the way it´s supposed to work. Could you try if this works from a second user account to see whether .DS_Store files in your folders are corrupted (as @Loïc suggests) or not?

Answer (score 1):

Before you resize the open window to your desired size, close all other Finder windows. If another Finder window is open, then your adjustments won't stick. Then close the adjusted window and try opening a window by switching using the File > New Finder Window command or by clicking on the Dock > Finder icon.

Note that it doesn't matter for me whether I select an item within the window before adjusting it. I'm running 10.6.6.

And if you're opening windows from a CD/DVD, then all bets are off.

Finally, if I resize the window and then rm .DS_Store, the new window still uses its most recent size/location.

Comment: I close all of my windows and open 1 window and resize it but next time it open smaller than the last time.

Comment: Is it the 'Home' folder that you are opening? I'm not sure if it will help but I've read that holding the option key while resizing the window will force it to remember. Or the control key. Just rumours but...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm not a 100 % sure about that one, but based on my experience, Finder save the window size/look for each folder. Probably in the ._DS_Store file.

So, it seems Finder has trouble accessing this file, or that the file is corrupt.

Try to delete the ._DS_Store file in your home folder (or whatever folder is opening when you "Open the Finder") and reopen the window.

Answer (score 0):

First off, each directory has a ._DS_Store file. Each one has a "memory" of how that folder was last displayed. Apple does have a tendency to open it at a "default" size. Any reason the "green" button isn't working?